# ctypes.ArgumentError Don't know how to convert parameter 1

Tags: python, fortran

I am getting this error (applying to x in the call to f in the definition of fun(x)):

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

when running this code:

```
import ctypes as ct
lib = ct.CDLL('x64\\Debug\\main2.dll')
f = getattr(lib,'MAIN2_MOD_mp_MAIN2')
f.restype = None
x = [2.0, 0.0]
def fun(x):
   objf = 0.0
   f(x,objf)
   return objf
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Update:
main2 is a Fortran subroutine:

```
module main2_mod
  contains
    !dec$ attributes dllexport :: main2
    subroutine main2(x,f)
    implicit none
    real(8), intent(inout) :: x(*)
    real(8), intent(  out) :: f
```

Comment: A Python list can be represented in different ways as an array in C. If you can provide documentation for or at least declaration of `MAIN2_MOD_mp_MAIN2` we may be able to tell you how to convert the list.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I added the definition of main2.

Comment: I don't know much about Fortran, therefore this is a guess: Replace `objf = 0.0` by `objf = c_double(0.0)` and `f(x,objf)` by `f((c_double * len(x))(*x), byref(objf))`.

Comment: It will be easier to use NumPy arrays instead of lists.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава as I'm a Fortran person I only understand arrays.  Didn't know I was using a list. I'll use whatever looks like an array...

Comment: If the list works, keep it. Fundamentally, a list can hold elements of any type, arrays holds elements of the same type. NumPy arrays have an internal representation compatible with C or Fortran arrays.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава aah so more like a structure. Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава How would this code look using numpy arrays? Particularly the f() Fortran call.

Comment: `x = np.asarray([2.0, 0.0])` and `f((ct.c_double * np.size(x))(*x), ct.byref(objf))`

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks, that works for passing the array in, however when I modify the array on the Fortran side, those changed values do not come back to Python in x.  Probably some by ref syntax needed?

Comment: You have `intent(in)` so you are not supposed to change it in the code you show.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава yes I have changed that to intent(inout) in my newest code. Updated above.

Comment: The syntax is `f(x.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)), ct.byref(objf))`.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава  Wow!  That works!  Where can I find documentation on this syntax?

Comment: In ctypes documentation and scattered in Stack Overflow questions and answers.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I now need to do the same for 1 2-d array, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001480/passing-a-modifiable-two-dimensional-array-from-python-to-fortran

Comment: @MichaelButscher I got all that working with my test code, now I'm integrating it into my mainline code.  One of the functions GETSIZE needs a char as the first argument (with 3 ints after).  I am getting a type error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78020185/why-am-i-getting-this-error-class-typeerror-wrong-type ... It seems the addition of fs.argtypes causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from Michael Butscher in the comments:

Replace

```
objf = 0.0
```

by

```
objf = ct.c_double(0.0)
```

and

```
f(x,objf)
```

by

```
f((ct.c_double * len(x))(*x), ct.byref(objf))
```

Comment: @MichaelButscher I need the list variable x to be modifiable by the Fortran code, however with the syntax f((c_double * len(x))(*x), byref(objf)) x retains its value in Python as it was before the call. Somehow Python needs to be told that x is modifiable by this Fortran call.