# Passing a modifiable two dimensional array from Python to Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

In a previous post [ctypes.ArgumentError Don't know how to convert parameter 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77989853/ctypes-argumenterror-dont-know-how-to-convert-parameter-1), I received a solution for passing a modifiable one dimensional array from Python to Fortran, which is (the first argument):

```
f(x.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)), ct.byref(objf)).
```

I now have a two dimensional array which needs to be sent and returned from Fortran.

The Fortran looks as follows:

```
!dec$ attributes dllexport :: getlincon
  subroutine getlincon(nr, lhs)
    integer, intent(in )  :: nr
    real(8), intent(out)  :: lhs(nr,*)
```

On the Python side, I have:  (there are nr=3 rows and nc=2 columns)

```
lib = ct.CDLL('x64\\Debug\\fortranobj.dll')
fl = getattr(lib,'FTN_OBJFUN_MOD_mp_GETLINCON')

nc = ct.c_int(2)
nr = ct.c_int(3)

lhs = [[np.zeros(int(nr.value))], [np.zeros(int(nc.value))]]  # initialize lhs

fl(ct.byref(nr), lhs.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)))
```

This fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ctypes'
```

Clearly I haven't got the Python syntax correct.

Comment: `lhs` is a strange thing. Why not `np.zeros([int(nr.value),int(nr.value)])`.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, thanks that works - however the 6 values are getting jumbled, probably a row/column definition difference between Python and Fortran.

Comment: Yes, `order="F"` should be added. See the manual on NumPy arrays.

Comment: Yes, got that. All works great now, thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this was voted down?  How do I get it back up again?

Comment: You never know, someone woted down because they did not like the question, but it is hard to say why. It is just one vote anyway. when someone votes up, it will get back to zero and you will even have a net gain of rep because a vote down takes away 2 but a vote up brings 10.

Answer (score 0):

As provided in the comments, correct syntax is:

```
lhs = np.zeros([int(nr.value),int(nc.value)],order='F')
```