# Why am I getting this error? <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I have a Python driver calling a Fortran subroutine.  The subroutine has 1 character, then 3 integers.  Before I added the character variable at the start and didn't have the argtypes call, it ran fine.  But adding the character (and its length) plus the artgtypes call at the start gives a TypeError:

```
import ctypes as ct
lib = ct.CDLL('FTN_lib.dll')
fs = getattr(lib,'PY_OBJFUN_MOD_mp_GETSIZE')
fs.restype = None
fs.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p,ct.c_int,ct.c_int,ct.c_int,ct.c_int]
x = b'x ' + sys.argv[1].encode('UTF-8') + b' debug=900'
n = ct.c_int(0)
nl = ct.c_int(0)
nnl = ct.c_int(0)
fs(x, len(x), ct.byref(n), ct.byref(nl), ct.byref(nnl))
```

> ```
> fs(x, len(x), ct.byref(n), ct.byref(nl), ct.byref(nnl))
> ```
>
> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

It seems the addition of fs.argtypes is causing the problem. The test code didn't have it, and it worked fine. Adding fs.argtypes causes the test code to fail too.  Hence there is some problem using ct.c_int construct which is used as ct_byref in the call.

The Fortran code header is:

```
  subroutine getsize(file,n,nl,nnl)
    implicit none
    character(*), intent(in ) :: file
    integer     , intent(out) :: n   
    integer     , intent(out) :: nl  
    integer     , intent(out) :: nnl
```

Comment: "The subroutine has 1 character, then 3 integers" - yet you provide an `argtypes` list of 1 character and **4 integers** - is the last integer supposed to be the return type? If so, assign it to `restype` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no there are 5 types in argtypes (char, its length, and 3 ints).  In Fortran a character is sent from Python (or C) as a char and a length.  Hence a Fortran character has two argument in Python.  There is no restype, it is a subroutine.

Comment: Gotcha. Try passing `ct.pointer(n)` instead of `ct.byref(n)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen nope exactly the same problem.  I'm using ct.byref is this worked in my test example, created from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77989853/ctypes-argumenterror-dont-know-how-to-convert-parameter-1.  The syntax fs(ct.byref(n), ct.byref(nl), ct.byref(nnl)) works fine without the character in Fortran / Python.  Just getting this error when I add the char.

Comment: Can you share the argument declarations from the subroutine?

Comment: The function is expecting *int*s (as you defined *argtypes*) but you're passing pointers. Why? `fs(x, ln, n, nl, nnl)`. There are lots of examples. [\[SO\]: Independent CDLL Library Instances with Ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257116/4788546), [\[SO\]: How to run a Fortran script with ctypes? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944691/4788546). Add the *Fortran* function so you have a *MCVE*.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have added the Fortran code header.

Comment: @CristiFati integer variables are passed to Fortran as pointers

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It seems the addition of fs.argtypes is causing the problem.  The test code didn't have it, and it worked fine.  Adding fs.argtypes causes the test code to fail too.

Comment: If using ctypes, it makes sense for your Fortran procedure to be C interoperable. Can you change your non-interoperable Fortran?

Comment: @francescalus I can change the Fortran.  What is non-interoperable therein?

Comment: The subroutine `getsize` is not interoperable, and its argument `file` is not interoperable, and the other arguments may not be.

Comment: Note that not specifying *argtypes*, is ***UB***: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: For C-interoperable procedures you in general employ the Fortran 2003 interoperability features. Those in general are the `bind(C)` attribute for the procedure and correct types for the arguments. Typically, you use kinds from the `iso_c_binding` module for interoperable types. Interoperable character arguments must be character arrays (len=1, not len=*) and you may not use stuff like allocatable or assumed shape arguments without further complications. So you would have something like `character(kind=c_char), intent(in ) :: file(*)` or `file(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran passes the integers by reference instead of by value. `argtypes` for the integer parameters should be `ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)`.

Note: A [comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23703182/235698) indicates the string size should be int32 on 32-bit systems and int64 on64-bit. I’d use `c_size_t`. It also says string lengths are added to the end of the parameter list and not interleaved. I don’t have Fortran to test.

Try:

```
fs.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.c_size_t
x = b'x ' + sys.argv[1].encode('UTF-8') + b' debug=900'
n = ct.c_int(0)
nl = ct.c_int(0)
nnl = ct.c_int(0)
fs(x, ct.byref(n), ct.byref(nl), ct.byref(nnl), len(x))
```